# Eclipse Plugin: Check if File in the Editor is Saved?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, editor

I'm building an Eclipse Plug-in and I would like to check to see if the current file in the editor has un-saved changes in it. Does anyone know how to do this? I've tried looking around and I assume it has something to do with:

```
 PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, you just keep going:

```
IWorkbenchPage page =  PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
IEditorPart editorPart = page.getActiveEditor();
if (editorPart.isDirty())
 ...
```